# can I use charToRaw to identify the special space that can help me separating a string into muti vars?

Tags: r

Is it a way to tell what charToRaw() outcome means?

I have a df like this:

```
df<- structure(list(X2 = c("Timepoint                                       EGTMPT      Categorical select one (nominal) 51         Screening", 
"N/A : O ff-Study                                EGTNA       Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Check if Not Done                               EGTMPTND    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Date Performed                                  ECGDT       Date                             11", 
"Time (24-hour format)                           ECGTM       Time                             5", 
"O verall ECG Interpretation                     ECGRES      Categorical select one (nominal) 37         Normal", 
"If A bnormal - Clinically Significant, describe ECGA BN     Text or A ny V alue              200", 
"PR Interval (ms)                                ECGPRIN     Number (continuous)              15", 
"Q RS Duration (ms)                              ECGQ RS     Number (continuous)              15", 
"Q TcF Interval (ms)                             EGQ TCF     Number (continuous)              15", 
"Timepoint                                       EG2TMPT     Categorical select one (nominal) 34         C11D01: Just Prior to Morning Dose", 
"N/A : O ff-Study                                EG2TNA      Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Check if Not Done                               EG2TPTND    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Date Performed                                  EG2DT       Date                             11", 
"Not Done                            PE2ND       Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3"
)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible to transfer them into charToRaw() all at once? I tried `df2<-charToRaw(df$X2, multiple = TRUE)` and it did not work. In fact, what I want to do whether I can separate those strings into 3 or 4 variables. Whether there is any specail blank between them and I can use it to seperate the string.

Any suggestion?

I can did one line, and the outcome is looks like this:

```
  [1] 54 69 6d 65 70 6f 69 6e 74 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
 [31] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 45 47 54 4d 50 54 20 20 20 20 20 20
 [61] 43 61 74 65 67 6f 72 69 63 61 6c 20 73 65 6c 65 63 74 20 6f 6e 65 20 28 6e 6f 6d 69 6e 61
 [91] 6c 29 20 35 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 53 63 72 65 65 6e 69 6e 67
```

Dose '20' means the blank that I can use for separate?

The outcome is sth that should looks like following:

[image]

Please note I also update 15th input. as my raw data can't be separated by fix length. Or at least i can't think of a way to make them into certain length limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `sapply/lapply`

```
sapply(df$X2, charToRaw)
```

---

We could try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(V1 = trimws(str_extract(X2, '.*\\s+(?=EC?G)')),
     V2 = trimws(str_extract(X2, '\\bEC?G[A-Z0-9]+\\s?[A-Z0-9]+?\\b')), 
     V3 = trimws(str_extract(str_remove(X2, '.*\\s+(?=EC?G)'), '\\b(Categ|Date|Tim|Text|Number).*'))) %>%
     transmute(across(matches('^V\\d+'), ~ str_replace_all(., '\\s{2,}', '\\s')))
#                                                V1       V2                                                                     V3
#1                                        Timepoint   EGTMPT                          Categorical select one (nominal) 51sScreening
#2                                 N/A : O ff-Study    EGTNA                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#3                                Check if Not Done EGTMPTND                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#4                                   Date Performed    ECGDT                                                                Dates11
#5                            Time (24-hour format)    ECGTM                                                                 Times5
#6                      O verall ECG Interpretation   ECGRES                             Categorical select one (nominal) 37sNormal
#7  If A bnormal - Clinically Significant, describe  ECGA BN                                                Text or A ny V alues200
#8                                 PR Interval (ms)  ECGPRIN                                                 Number (continuous)s15
#9                               Q RS Duration (ms)  ECGQ RS                                                 Number (continuous)s15
#10                             Q TcF Interval (ms)  EGQ TCF                                                 Number (continuous)s15
#11                                       Timepoint  EG2TMPT Categorical select one (nominal) 34sC11D01: Just Prior to Morning Dose
#12                                N/A : O ff-Study   EG2TNA                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#13                               Check if Not Done EG2TPTND                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#14                                  Date Performed    EG2DT                                                                Dates11
#15                           Time (24-hour format)    EG2TM                                                                 Times5
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
read.csv(text= sub("^(.*[a-z\\)])\\s([A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]+|[A-Z]+\\s[A-Z]+)\\s([A-Z][a-z].*)", "\\1;\\2;\\3", 
     gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", df$X2)), header = FALSE, col.names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), sep=";")
#                                                V1       V2                                                                     V3
#1                                        Timepoint   EGTMPT                          Categorical select one (nominal) 51 Screening
#2                                 N/A : O ff-Study    EGTNA                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#3                                Check if Not Done EGTMPTND                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#4                                   Date Performed    ECGDT                                                                Date 11
#5                            Time (24-hour format)    ECGTM                                                                 Time 5
#6                      O verall ECG Interpretation   ECGRES                             Categorical select one (nominal) 37 Normal
#7  If A bnormal - Clinically Significant, describe  ECGA BN                                                Text or A ny V alue 200
#8                                 PR Interval (ms)  ECGPRIN                                                 Number (continuous) 15
#9                               Q RS Duration (ms)  ECGQ RS                                                 Number (continuous) 15
#10                             Q TcF Interval (ms)  EGQ TCF                                                 Number (continuous) 15
#11                                       Timepoint  EG2TMPT Categorical select one (nominal) 34 C11D01: Just Prior to Morning Dose
#12                                N/A : O ff-Study   EG2TNA                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#13                               Check if Not Done EG2TPTND                                     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3
#14                                  Date Performed    EG2DT                                                                Date 11
#15                           Time (24-hour format)    EG2TM                                                                 Time 5
```

Comment: Thanks. :D Do you know what `20` stands for? I am thinking of using gsub("20 20" , "20" ) then use `20` as strsplit. Do you think it is doable? And then maybe to rawtochar?

Comment: @Stataq it is for the space character `charToRaw(substr(df$X2[1], 1, 9))#
[1] 54 69 6d 65 70 6f 69 6e 74#
> charToRaw(substr(df$X2[1], 10, 10))#
[1] 20`

Comment: @Stataq what is your expected ouptut

Comment: for '"Check if Not Done                               EGTMPTND    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", I would like to separate it  into at least 3 parts:  `Check if Not Done`, `EGTMPTND`, `Categorical yes/no (dichotomous)` `3`. the last 2 can be together.

Comment: I did the similar way `t5<-data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(t4$X2),  "\\s{2,}" )), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` but ran into the same problem as your codes. you can see #7,  it did not separated as I want. The raw data is too messy. :(

Comment: @Stataq what do you want for 7.  Can you pleaes update your post with expected output so that it is more clear

Comment: `ECGA BN`  should be in V2, and the space should be removed. it should be 'ECGABN'. at the end, the space in V2 will be removed.

Comment: @Stataq can you please update your post with expected so that I can crosscheck

Comment: I just updated the post with expected outcome.

Comment: Is it Ok for me to separate the string with " " then combined any two col that are both capitalized? Just a thought.

Comment: @Stataq My new update is getting almost same results as you want.  If you wwant to remove the space from V2, just do `%>% mutate(V2 = str_remove_all(V2, "\\s+"))`

Comment: As V2 are not always EC.., Is it possible to make the cutoff  as any capitalized letters at the end?